# Leaflet v1 plugin: layer control for ungrouped, grouped, and nested-grouped layers

Tags: leaflet, layers, plugins, group-layer

I need a Leaflet plugin which extends `L.Control.Layers`. I have the following requirements:

- works with Leaflet 1.x
- handles ungrouped layers alongside grouped ones
- handles nested layer groups
- does not rely on actual Leaflet LayerGroups, but can be built up independently (in other words, layers can be grouped in this control in a different structure to how the layers themselves are grouped in the Leaflet map)

I've tried:

- https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol (doesn't seem to handle ungrouped layers)
- https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-panel-layers (can't get it to work at all)
- https://github.com/robbiet480/leaflet-categorized-layers (also can't get this to work)

Can anyone suggest if any plugin does what I need?

BOUNTY ADDED
To qualify for the bounty, please link to or upload a fully working example using Leaflet 1.x, including in the custom layer control:

- ungrouped layers
- grouped layers
- nested groups

Comment: Maybe you check out https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. It'd make more sense to ask WHY the plugins you already linked are not working for you, and try investigating that.

Comment: @Senshi I have, and most plugin authors say that nested groups are out of scope for their plugins.

Comment: do you mean grouping together items like tile layers separate to your geojson file ?

Comment: Greta question, and I would love to know the answer. Of course, nowadays, I would ask on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)